# Difference between underscore js _.each method and _.invoke method

Tags: underscore.js

I am not able to understand the difference between [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/) methods [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) and [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke).
Both seems to invoke the function passed on each item.

Under which scenario shall I use `_.each` and `_.invoke`?

Please share the difference with some examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they do different things. Have a look at their code!

- [`each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) calls a given function with each element of a given object. You can additionally pass it a context on which the functions are applied. It acts like the native `forEach` on arrays.

  ```
  iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj)
  ```

  It does return undefined.
- [`invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) usually gets a method name as a string, and looks up the method dynamically for each element of the given set. Then it applies the method on that element; and you additionally can pass it some arguments.

  ```
  (_.isFunction(method) ? method : obj[i][method]).apply(obj[i], args);
  ```

  It does return the results of the invocations, it basically does `map`.